# Error in CORS PHP - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: php, angular, cors

I'm developing an application in which I make an image upload request.

And it gives me the following error when sending the image for upload:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Below is a snippet of the code in Angular:

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${this.baseUrl}/uploads/upload.php`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'json'
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
```

Below is a snippet of the code in PHP:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 60");
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    header("HTTP/2 200 OK");
    header("Status 200");
```

Does anyone have a possible solution for this BUG?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to add OPTIONS to the allowed methods, and the name of your domain to allowed origin. Make sure the the target server is setup to return the OPTIONS method in the header of the preflight response.

Answer (score -1):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
add this  line in header.

Comment: I already did, and the problem still remains